# How to remove or clear data of dc.dataTable?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

We have added a line chart, time slider and data table in our html page.

When users click on the 'Clear All' button we want to remove our line chart, time slider and data table.

The line chart and time slider are removed using

```
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
```

How do we remove / clear the data table?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could do

```
$("#clearButton").click(function() {
    $("#datatable").css("display", "none");
});
```

where "clearButton" is the id of your button and "datatable" is the id of your data table HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RefreshTable() {
                datatable.fnClearTable();
            };
RefreshTable() ;
dc.renderAll() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I think you talk about http://www.datatables.net/

We are using data table of dc charting library (https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#data-table)